# How can I obtain a uniform bacterial sample?

Tags: species-identification, microbiology, bacteriology, pathology

I'm currently doing a research project wherein I will be testing the antibiotic resistance of a bacterial sample. Due to a risk of contamination during transport, I'm not allowed to request a uniform bacterial sample form a clinical laboratory. So, I have to produce my own sample. Then, I'm planning to identify the morphology of the bacteria to confirm the species or type.

The ideal scenario is obtaining a sample which is entirely one species of bacteria. However, taking a swab, either from somewhere in the lab or from the body will produce a sample with multiple bacterial species. What source of bacteria can provide the most uniform sample, i.e. a sample with a majority of one species of bacteria? Or, is there another way to obtain a uniform sample? Also, note: I will be conducting the experiment in a school laboratory, so I must be able to safely contain the pathogen.

Edit: I have recently updated my project to be specified towards testing on bacteria present in the throat. So, a bacteria present in this area or similar areas would be preferable.

Comment: Do you have a particular bacteria in mind? For safety, I have a link. Especially culture well below body temperature, and use common media e.g nutrient agar. https://www.riskassess.com.au/info/micro_issues

Comment: I have no specific species/strain in mind. However, I have recently updated my project to be specified towards bacteria in the throat. So, a bacteria which is present there or in similar areas would be preferable (I'll also update the question).

Comment: This is what streak plating is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could inoculate your sample in [a selective medium or an enrichment medium](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/microbiology/chapter/media-used-for-bacterial-growth/) to kill off the unwanted species. Of course, you will need to do a literature search to find the optimum medium for the species of your interest.

Another option is to streak plates [like so](https://youtu.be/oPl4ETb3vMg). With successive 'generations' of streaks, the inoculum gets diluted, so that you ultimately get separate colonies. Each colony is founded by a single bacterial cell: by picking up one such colony, you get a pure sample.

For even better results, combine both the methods described above by first growing in a selective medium and then streaking on a solid medium to get individual colonies.